# Vue2 - Accessing to methods of a component with a generated ref name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access to a method of an child component, to validate multiple forms.

I have an array named "forms", each form object has a randomly generated id. Based on these form objects I generate components and give them a ref name

In my validateAll method I'm trying to loop over all forms, find components with their id as component's ref name. When I find the component (no problem so far), I try to call the child's method. But I get an error.

This is where I render components with v-for loop:

```
<SupportRequestForm v-for="(form, idx) in forms" :key="form.id"
    ...
    :ref="`formRef${form.id}`"
/>
```

This is validateAll method, where I try to access child method:

```
validateAllForms() {
    return this.forms.find(form => {
        const formComponent = this.$refs[`formRef${form.id}`]
        console.log(formComponent)
        return formComponent.validateForm()
    })
}
```

And this is the error:
[image: error]

I can access child component's method when it's a static ref name but I can't do the same thing when the is generated on the spot. Is this an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The function validate forms does not exist. The function you provided is called validateAllForms. Is this a typo?

Comment: No it's not, validateForm is the method of the child component (SupportRequestForm), which I'm trying to call.

Comment: why are you using find the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bind each form to the form id, just create one ref called `forms` and since it's used with `v-for` it will contain the forms array :

> When ref is used together with v-for, the ref you get will be an array containing the child components mirroring the data source

```
<SupportRequestForm v-for="(form, idx) in forms" :key="form.id" ref="forms" />
```

in method :

```
validateAllForms() {
     this.$refs.forms.forEach(formComponent=> {
       formComponent.validateForm()
    })
}
```